# getline truncating input in buffer overflow control example

Tags: c++, cin, getline, buffer-overflow

So I'm coming up with a simple solution to control and notify the user if a buffer overflow is detected.
First, the input char array is set up using a size variable, and then the getline function takes in input up to that size.

```
    const int charMax = 20;
    const std::string account_number = "CharlieBrown42";
    char user_input[charMax];

    std::cout << "Enter a value: ";
    std::cin.getline(user_input, charMax);
```

Then I check and see if there is anything left in the buffer -- if so, I let the user know that buffer overflow was attempted, but only the right amount of input was read.

```
    if ((std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() - 2) > 0) {
         std::cout << "Buffer overflow was attempted, but input was automatically trimmed" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "You entered: " << user_input << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Account Number = " << account_number << std::endl;
```

However, when tested, the printed final user_input is always only 19 characters.  This is problematic because I am supposed to be able to take in up to 20 characters before buffer overflow occurs ( > charMax).  getline() is always truncating one character more than I need it to.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Character arrays used as strings must have a terminating 0. If you give a limit of 20 that means up to 19 characters plus the terminating 0. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

Comment: Hmm.  When I go to getline(user_input, charMax + 1), I get a buffer overflow error.  Is there a way to make it take everything I put in without the trailing zero?

Comment: You cannot avoid the terminating 0, it is what makes a character array usable as a nul terminated string. You can increase your buffer size or use `std::string` which will resize to fit the available data. `std::string s; std::getline(std::cin, s);`